# PaymentRequestForm for stripe integration is not visible in the browser

Tags: reactjs, stripe.js, stripe-payments

I am integrating react-stripe-elements for interating stripe for my application. I have used a `SplitForm` component. After integrating this, I have all the form details and pay button.
When I click on the pay button, I get a token for the card details.
But the payment request form is not visible in my browser. 
How do I send the amount from `paymentrequest`?

I have read the docs but I did not find any proper information on this. My code is below:

```
 <StripeProvider apiKey="pk_live_29VEENvMXTK8wZCb8xI6EO0B">                   
    <Checkout />                
 </StripeProvider>



class _PaymentRequestForm extends React.Component{
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
const paymentRequest = props.stripe.paymentRequest({
  country: 'US',
  currency: 'usd',
  total: {
    label: 'Demo total',
    amount: 1000,
  },
});

paymentRequest.on('token', ({complete, token, ...data}) => {
  console.log('Received Stripe token: ', token);
  console.log('Received customer information: ', data);
  complete('success');
});

paymentRequest.canMakePayment().then(result => {
  this.setState({canMakePayment: !!result});
});

this.state = {
  canMakePayment: false,
  paymentRequest,
};
}
  render() {
 return this.state.canMakePayment ? (
  <PaymentRequestButtonElement
    className="PaymentRequestButton"
    paymentRequest={this.state.paymentRequest}

  />
) : null;
  }
  }
const PaymentRequestForm = injectStripe(_PaymentRequestForm);
class Checkout extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  elementFontSize: window.innerWidth < 450 ? '14px' : '18px',
};
 }
render() {
const {elementFontSize} = this.state;
return (
  <div className="Checkout">
    <Elements>
    <PaymentRequestForm />
    </Elements>
  </div>
  );
 }

 }
```

Comment: Tried to improve formatting, question title and grammar. Please check that this is still saying what you want!

Comment: simple and clear, I can able to generate the token via card details but i cannot able to send amount, How to send amount?

Answer (score 1):

Are you accessing the page via https? I had the same issue. Turns out you need to be on an https connection for the payment form to show up. The local React development server does not provide ssl encrypted access. For me the solution was to use ngrok and point it at port 3000 where my local react app was running.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to keep the `amount` somewhere else, and provide it both to the PaymentRequest object, and also send it along with the Token to your server-side code that will create the Charge.

In terms of the Payment Request button not appearing, that's hard to answer without more information, but you should see it if you visit the page in Chrome with a saved (test) card.

Comment: where i need to keep the mount somewhere else? can you guide me where to place
And how to save test card in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but i recently had the same issue and i found out the problem was with the naming of my react component. React components are supposed to start with a capital letter else it wouldn't render. In your particular case, you would need to change the following code block;

```js
class _PaymentRequestForm extends React.Component{
...
}
```

To

```js
class PaymentRequestForm extends React.Component{
...
}
```

Hope this solves it for the next person, also kindly mark this as useful if it helps.